# OrientDB difference between vertex label and vertex class

Tags: java, graph, orientdb

I just started using orientDB and I'm confused whether I have to use label or class.

```
public Iterable<com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex> getVertices(String label,
                                                             String[] iKey,
                                                             Object[] iValue)
```

Uses label, but I couldn't find what that label stands for.
If I want to have it from a specific category "Animal" "Company" etc do I have to get and store it as a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrive all the vertices from a class you can use this:

```
Iterable<Vertex> result2=g.getVerticesOfClass("Person");
            for(Vertex v:result2){  
                String rid=v.getId().toString();
                String name=v.getProperty("name");
                String surname=v.getProperty("surname");
                System.out.println(rid + " " + name + " " + surname);  
            }
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the command posted above you have to do something like this:

```
        String [] properties = {"name"};
        String [] value = {"pluto"};

        Iterable<Vertex> i_ad = g.getVertices("Animal", properties, value);
        for(Vertex v:i_ad){ 
            System.out.println(v.getProperty("name").toString());
        }
```

label stands for the name of the class.

And there's no other way to avoid the iteration.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: I want to know what the difference between label and class is.
And is there no better api than iterating through all elements of a certain class? That's kinda costly.

Comment: Thanks, that's better =D.